# undeclared identifier error with a structure in C

Tags: c, enums, structure, undeclared-identifier

I have a structure `ST_transaction_t` that contains 2 structures, an enumeration and `uint32_t` members, when I declare the structure `ST_transaction account1` I get `account1': undeclared identifier error`. When I remove the enumeration typed member from the structure it works.

Here is the part of the code with the problem:

```
typedef struct ST_transaction_t
{
    ST_cardData_t cardHolderData;
    ST_terminalData_t terminalData;
    EN_transState_t transState;
    uint32_t transactionSequenceNumber;
}ST_transaction_t;
typedef enum EN_transState_t
{
    APPROVED, DECLINED_INSUFFECIENT_FUND, DECLINED_STOLEN_CARD, INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
}EN_transState_t;

int main() {
ST_transaction_t account1 ;
return 0;
}
```

Now if did this:

```
typedef struct ST_transaction_t
{
    ST_cardData_t cardHolderData;
    ST_terminalData_t terminalData;
    //EN_transState_t transState;
    uint32_t transactionSequenceNumber;
}ST_transaction_t;
typedef enum EN_transState_t
{
    APPROVED, DECLINED_INSUFFECIENT_FUND, DECLINED_STOLEN_CARD, INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
}EN_transState_t;

int main() {
ST_transaction_t account1 ;
return 0;
}
```

It works perfectly, so why is that `EN_transState_t transState` causing that error and how to fix it ?

Comment: You must define EN_transState_t before using it, ie before ST_transaction_t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `typedef enum EN_transState_t` is only declared after its use in `typedef struct ST_transaction_t`. In C all types must be declared before it can be referenced. The compiler works from the top down.

Move the declaration `typedef enum EN_transState_t` to before `typedef struct ST_transaction_t`and your code should work.

Answer (score 1):

you problem is not about variable called `EN_transState_t transState;` itself, rather it's about its typedef place in the code , I mean when the compiler compiles your code line by line and comes to this line  `EN_transState_t transState;` , there is no previous declaration of such a type , as the declaration of such a type is mentioned in later lines meaning that `EN_transState_t transState;` comes before these lines:

```
   typedef enum EN_transState_t
   {
        APPROVED, DECLINED_INSUFFECIENT_FUND, DECLINED_STOLEN_CARD, INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR 

    }EN_transState_t;
```

so you have to :

```
typedef enum EN_transState_t
{
    APPROVED, DECLINED_INSUFFECIENT_FUND, DECLINED_STOLEN_CARD, INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
}EN_transState_t;

typedef struct ST_transaction_t
{
    ST_cardData_t cardHolderData;
    ST_terminalData_t terminalData;
    EN_transState_t transState;
    uint32_t transactionSequenceNumber;
}ST_transaction_t;


int main() {
ST_transaction_t account1 ;
return 0;
}
```